# Is there processor/plugin out there that would enforce referential-transparency, immutabiliyt, etc. in Java?

Tags: java, functional-programming, referential-transparency

It seems pretty straightforward:
For example, an @Immutable on a class that the processor would then give error if there were any non-final field accesses. It would have to ensure that all collaborators were also immutable.

A @ReferentiallyTransparent (better name?) could be put on methods that would then check to ensure that all calls and collaborators were also marked @RefTrans and @Immutable...

Comment: You could write a tool to do this using reflections.  For a more low level check you could use ASM.  I generate my immutable data value objects so I don't need to check if they are final. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be interested by the following paper : [Verifiable Functional Purity in Java](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~finifter/pure-ccs08.pdf)

Abstract :

> Proving that particular methods within a code base are functionally
>   pure — deterministic and side-effect free — would aid verification of
>   security properties including function invertibility, reproducibility
>   of computation, and safety of untrusted code execution. Until now it
>   has not been possible to automatically prove a method is functionally
>   pure within a high-level imperative language in wide use, such as
>   Java. We discuss a technique to prove that methods are functionally
>   pure by writing programs in a subset of Java called Joe-E; a static
>   verifier ensures that programs fall within the subset. In Joe-E, pure
>   methods can be trivially recognized from their method signature. To
>   demonstrate the practicality of our approach, we refactor an AES
>   library, an experimental voting machine implementation, and an HTML
>   parser to use our techniques. We prove that their top-level methods
>   are verifiably pure and show how this provides high-level security
>   guarantees about these rou- tines. Our approach to verifiable purity
>   is an attractive way to permit functional-style reasoning about
>   security properties while leveraging the familiarity, convenience, and
>   legacy code of imperative languages.